# JDBC url for MySQL configuration to use utf8 character encoding

Tags: mysql, jdbc, encoding, utf-8, collation

### MySQL 5.6 Configuration

I have configured `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` manually to use `utf8`. See below:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets

[mysql]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqladmin]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqlcheck]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqldump]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqlimport]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[mysqlshow]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8

[client]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets default-character-set=utf8
```

From console:

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

### Application configuration

Now for the web-app I used both of this connection url in Tomcat's `context.xml`

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"

url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=utf8&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci"
```

Above does not work and gives me following for the application.

```
show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

---

What might be wrong here? Why it is showing `utf8mb4` instead `utf8`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may have to do with the following:

[Changes in MySQL Connector/J 5.1.13 (2010-06-24)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/en/news-5-1-13.html)

- Connector/J did not support utf8mb4 for servers 5.5.2 and newer.

  Connector/J now auto-detects servers configured with `character_set_server=utf8mb4` or treats the Java encoding utf-8 passed using `characterEncoding=...` as `utf8mb4` in the `SET NAMES=` calls it makes when establishing the connection. (Bug #54175)

Comment: Updating to latest mysql driver solved my problem. @William hint is correct.

Comment: `utf8mb4` is MySQL's `UTF-8`. If you use `utf8` in MySQL, you're missing out on an important portion of Unicode (the astral symbols). Switch everything, tables, database, to `utf8mb4` or you may lose data. Yeah, I know, ridiculous, right? They must have confused the day they coded this in for a night out.

Comment: Still, it seem like it should have set `character_set_connection` to utf8mb4, as `SET NAMES` does.

Comment: MySQL originally used 3 bytes to encode `utf8`... this is wrong. UTF8 uses up to a [maximum of 4 bytes](http://stijndewitt.com/2014/08/09/max-bytes-in-a-utf-8-char/). But having to remain backwards compatible with their old bugs, they sorta fixed it by introducing `utf8mb4`, which is the same encoding the rest of the world calls UTF8. So, [use utf8mb4 if you want full unicode support](http://stijndewitt.com/2015/06/15/use-mysql-utf8mb4-if-you-want-full-unicode-support/). The bad thing is few people know this, so new systems keep getting created using the wrong encoding.

Comment: This version you say not works for me, I use mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar instead

Answer (score 0):

For your web-app please try `characterEncoding=utf8` instead of UTF-8.  That resolved my SonarQube container issue.