# Json question marks ("??????") instead of Hebrew chars

Tags: java, mysql, json, servlets, utf-8

I am getting data from my db which contains words in Hebrew. Then I am getting this data from `ResultSet` putting into a String and then putting it to a `JSONObject`.

Here is the code:

```
response.setContentType(application/json);
...
String str = rs.getString['name'];
...
JSONObject obj = new JSONObj();
obj.put("name", str);
...
response.getWriter().write(obj.toString());
```

**Note:**

I am using java as my backend and my db is mysql. The db configured to UTF-8

**Result:**

```
{"name":"??????"}
```

Comment: What character set are you using?

Comment: DOes EVERYTHING use UTF8? That is: all scripts are saved in UTF8 (the files themselfes!), all network requests use utf8, SQL-transaktions are using UTF8 and, last but not least, your database collation is UTF8?

Comment: Where are you seeing this output? A front-end app, a console, etc...it might not be a d/b problem; it might be a display problem (or a problem with the JSON library).

Comment: The characters are there. The ability of your console device to display them is not.

Comment: @ Space Pope I am making an http request to my back end, I see the output in my browser. Chrome browser.

Comment: Does the browser actually display UTF8? What is the content-type heder in the HTTP response?

Comment: For a long time you had to specify the charset in the jdbc connection string for MySQL. You might want to look into that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058297/jdbc-url-for-mysql-configuration-to-use-utf8-character-encoding

Comment: Solved it with @ Johannes H help. added `response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");`

Comment: Glad I could help. :) Take the credit for the answer yourself, I really only pointed the direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it with @ Johannes H help. added `response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");`