# Incorrect String value without "?characterEncoding=UTF-8"

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to insert some text in a field in my database and I have a problem with emojis. What happens is that if I don't set my connection url to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDatabase?characterEncoding=UTF-8` then the server will store the emojis just fine but will also store non-latin characters as question marks.

Now if I set my connection url like that then the server will not like the emojis and will output the error:

`Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\xB1\xF0\x9F...' for column 'fullTweet' at row 1`

I have done all the necessary steps for utf8 compatibility on my local server:

1. I added the line `character-set-server=utf8mb4` to `my.ini`
2. The query `show variables like 'character_set_server'` returns `utf8mb4`
3. I create my database with the query `CREATE DATABASE twitter DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`
4. and by default all of my tables and fields of my tables are using `utf8mb4_general_ci` (as I can see in `phpmyadmin`)

What is missing? I am sure I did all the necessary steps and I still can't get this to work, either it will store only latin characters or it won't store emoji.

---

**Additional information from a previous question of mine:**

I can manually enter the emoji in the database and they show exactly as they show in the debugger (as boxes). I run this query:

```
INSERT INTO `tweets`(`id`, `createdAt`, `screenName`, `fullTweet`, `editedTweet`) VALUES (450,"1994-12-19","john",_utf8mb4 x'F09F98B1',_utf8mb4 x'F09F98B1')
```

and this is what the row in the table looks like:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in details in [How to support full Unicode in MySQL databases · Mathias Bynens](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4)
Basically, I think you miss this (from [Step 5](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#character-sets))

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Then, you should remove `characterEncoding=UTF-8` from your URL.
Also check you have MySQL Connector/J 5.1.13+ (see [JDBC url for MySQL configuration to use utf8 character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058297/jdbc-url-for-mysql-configuration-to-use-utf8-character-encoding))

Answer (score 0):

Try this-->

```
convert('string' using utf8)
```

or

```
convert('string',char)
```

or

```
convert('string' using latin1)
```

or use whatever the character encoding is that you have set in the table.
The code I have provided are mysql functions.

Comment: I can't find any such functions, they are not getting recognized.