# mysql connectorJ character set results does not support utf8mb4

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, mysql-connector, connector-j

I m having a tomcat server having a connection pool to mysql.

In the connection settings i can see all the character set encodings set to utf8mb4 in [*this page](http://nvoids.com/conSet.jsp) except for character_set_results.

My connection string being -

```
 jdbc:mysql://:3306/abc?character_set_server=utf8mb4&useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true&character_set_connection=utf8mb4&characterEncoding=utf-8&character_set_results=utf8mb4
```

In the mysql server i can see character_set_results showing utf8mb4.

But in the jsp page it is not shown anyway.

The mysql version is 5.6.16 and connector version is 5.1.22

Regards

Comment: Try: `...&characterSetResults=utf8mb4`

Comment: `(...&characterSetResults=utf8)` solved the problem and it is now showing the character_set_results as utf8mb4. `(...&characterSetResults=utf8mb4)` is not supported and throws a error while connecting.

Comment: Check: [JDBC url for MySQL configuration to use utf8 character encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058297/jdbc-url-for-mysql-configuration-to-use-utf8-character-encoding)

Answer (score 3):

connection settings need not characterEncoding and character_set_server, mysql connectorJ will auto check.

make sure character_set_database=utf8mb4,character_set_server=utf8mb4,
Table character set=utf8mb4, some columns use varchar character set=utf8mb4;

tip: character_set_server=utf8mb4 need config my.ini 
Exemple:

```
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'

loose-default-character-set = utf8mb4
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
loose-default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html?spm=5176.2020520165.110.53.AlPmXp

Comment: Please don't post answers in both English and Chinese - StackOverflow is English only. Thanks!