# ormlite change characters with question marks

Tags: java, mysql, ormlite

I use of following query in ormlite with Mysql:

```
String _textSearch="%اعصاب%";
Where<QuestionEntity, Long> _where= getDao().queryBuilder()).where();

List<QuestionEntity> _lst= _where.or(_where.like("title",_textSearch ),
    _where.like("questiontext", _textSearch)).query();
```

but generate following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `question`
    WHERE (`title` LIKE '%?????%' OR `questiontext` LIKE '%?????%' )
```

why ?

Comment: Find out how to configure ormlite to use utf8.

Comment: How are you seeing the query?  In the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `question`
    WHERE (`title` LIKE '%?????%' OR `questiontext` LIKE '%?????%' )
```

Hrm, I'm not sure what the problem is here.  I've added the [this UTF8 query-build test](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/e6f1d1880d6d0ea78407f8920339abb641d9ee11) to the ormlite-core project and it passes fine.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.stringField = "اعصاب";
dao.create(foo);
List<Foo> results = dao.queryBuilder().where()
   .like(Foo.STRING_COLUMN_NAME, foo.stringField).query();
assertEquals(foo.stringField, results.get(0).stringField);
```

This generates the following log output:

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `string` LIKE 'اعصاب'
```

This also works with a `SelectArg` which is how [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) does `?` args.

```
statement arguments: [اعصاب]
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `string` LIKE ?
```

I initially thought that this was a problem with MySQL.  Maybe you got the queries out of the server log?  If you got the '?????' from a local log then I'm not sure what the issue is.  Maybe the default character encoding for your application?

The tests are using H2 which is a native Java DB so can easily handle Java's strings.  Maybe take a look at these MySQL questions/answers for help:

- [How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly)
- [JDBC url for MySQL configuration to use utf8 character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058297/jdbc-url-for-mysql-configuration-to-use-utf8-character-encoding)

There is some talk about later versions of the MySQL connector fixing a problem with detecting the character type of the database.