# Getting [SqlExceptionHelper] Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x90\xBE V...' although the table is in UTF-8

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, utf-8

In my java project, I keep getting `[SqlExceptionHelper] Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x90\xBE V...'`, although MySQL Workbench show that the table is in UTF-8, and adding in the workbench the value "Brandst**ä**tter" works.

I changed in the workbench the collation from utf8 to utf8mb4, and that did not work. Also, in the java project, I have in my application.properties file: `jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/recommendations?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8` (changing `utf8` to `utf8mb4` coused `Unsupported character encoding 'utf8mb4'`).

Also, this returns `utf8`: `SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S WHERE schema_name = "db-name"`;

What can I do?

**Edit:** The data being inserted: "Loy ߐ¾ Virtual Pet Game".

**Edit2:** Now that I look more closly, [this application's name](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.frojo.loy.android) coases the problem. What should I do? Neglect the weird chars (with `Character.isISOControl`, or is there a collation even more powerful then UTF-8?

Comment: Can you add your java code that insert the data to your DB?

Comment: monkeyStix - as i've said, I tried to state utf8mb4 but it didn't work. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: what version of mysql do you use?

Comment: @Ran, do you use Spring JDBC?

Comment: Yes, I use Spring. Also, MySQL said when I tried to export the data on it that it is in version 5.7.12.

Comment: @Ran If you use Spring, you have to build parameter map for your insert quury, so yo can either use `Map<String, Object>` or `SqlParameterSource` for it. Make sure you don't pass any custom objects to this map, it should contain DB compatible values, otherwise the custom object might be serialized to a binary data, and these data in turn would be written as a string to the DB. So binary data represented as a string may contain some illegal characters.

Comment: My entities are simple POJO's made out of ints and Strings. No custom objects, just plain Strings. The data I put in them comes from Google Play's website, with URLConnection and InputStream classes. Can URLConnection or InputStream contain non-utf-8 data? How can I handle it?

Comment: `ä` works in both utf8 and utf8mb4.

Answer (score 1):

You need `utf8mb4` in your table *and* in your connection to the database.

Here's the clue:

```
\xF0\x9F\x90\xBE
```

Notice the first byte is hex `F0`.  That is the UTF8 lead-in for a 4-byte 'character'.  MySQL's `utf8` does not handle longer than 3 bytes; `utf8mb4` does.

Note:  Outside MySQL, "UTF-8" means characters of any length.  Inside MySQL there is the confusing distinction between "utf8" and "utf8mb4".

Comment: How do I set it? I tried in the jdbc.url and failed (see my question), and it didn't help me to set in in MySQL via the workbench.

Comment: What version of JDBC?  Of MySQL?

Comment: No idea of JDBC, MySQL is 5.7.12/13

Comment: Any better here?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13754976/1766831

Comment: Possible Connector/J issues:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18059663/1766831

Comment: I changed the column collation to utf8mb4 in the workbench, but that didn't help. Do I need to change something else?

Comment: "utf8mb4" is a "character set", not a "collation".  (I'm running out of ideas.)

Comment: Where do I put this "character set"? In MySQL it doesn't work and in url.jdbc it throws exception.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`