# execute query in java not return results but in mysql workbench still return results

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This query:

```
    SELECT 
    r.report_id,
    r.user_id,
    u.user_name,
    u.user_mail,
    d.department_name,
    r.report_comment,
    r.report_target_date,
    r.report_create_date,
    r.report_revised_date,
    r.report_root_id,
    report_revised_id
FROM
    report r
        JOIN
    user u ON u.user_id = r.user_id
        JOIN
    department d ON u.department_id = d.department_id
        JOIN
    authority a ON r.user_id = a.user_src_id
        AND a.user_dest_id = 131
WHERE
    r.report_target_date BETWEEN '2014-07-23 23:59:00' AND '2014-08-22 00:00:00'
    AND r.report_comment LIKE '%事務%'
```

In mysql workbench this query has return value but when using it in java it's not returning anything:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs = null;
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

In mysql workbench this query has return value but rs return is empty.

Comment: No way. executeQuery never returns null. It might return an empty result set, but never null. Clarify your question, show us the code, and tell us exactly what happens.

Comment: use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to set the values in query.

Comment: Maybe that is an encoding problem with you special characters. can you try to remove the part `AND r.report_comment LIKE ..` and try if you get a result?

Comment: remove r.report_comment LIKE '%事務%' execute is working well. I don't know why.

Comment: Sorry i'm mistake about said rs return null.It is empty.

Comment: first remove last where clause and try if it returns valid result. If so then there might be a issue using Unicode characters

Answer (score 2):

You pass Japanese characters into the query. This could easily be a character encoding issue.

Use a `PreparedStatement` and insert the value through a `setString()` call which will properly take care of the encoding.

Modify your `query` to have a parameter (marked by a question mark):

```
...
WHERE
    r.report_target_date BETWEEN '2014-07-23 23:59:00' AND '2014-08-22 00:00:00'
    AND r.report_comment LIKE ?
```

And the Java code:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, "%事務%"); // Parameter index is 1-based
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: In the past i already using PreparedStatement and set value but not work. After that i try execute directly like that but still not work. What wrong in this step ??

Comment: Make sure your Java source files are using UTF-8, and also the Java compiler (javac) interprets them as UTF-8. Also make sure your JDBC also uses UTF-8, here is how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040597/jdbc-character-encoding

Comment: Agree with others that looking at the encoding of Japanese characters is the right direction to go.